# Image now has yellow tint after redrawing from its RGB values

Tags: image, processing

I wanted to create a printer(esc) program so I took an imagine and converted it into its RGB values with Python:

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("pic.png").convert("RGB")
pxls = list(img.getdata())
with open("picrgb.txt", "a+") as f:
    for i in pxls:
        line = ""
        for c in range(3):
            line += f",{i[c]}"
        line = line.lstrip(",")
        f.write(line + " \n")
```

Then I read that text file into processing by doing:

```java
String[] lines;
int x, y;

void setup() {
  size(220, 220, P2D);
  background(255);
  lines = loadStrings("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\picrgbs.txt");
  println(lines.length);
  frameRate(1000);
}
```

Then created a function to 'print' the image and called it in draw:

```java
void printer() {
  if (y < lines.length) {
    if (x < width) {
      String[] pxl = split(lines[x+y], ",");
      int r = int(pxl[0]);
      int g = int(pxl[1]);
      int b = int(pxl[2]);
      fill(r, g, b);
      stroke(r, g, b);
      rect(x, y/width, 1, 1);
      x++;
    } else {
      x = 0;
      y += width;
    }
  } else {
    noLoop();
  }
}
```

Can anyone see why this is giving a yellow tint to the image?

Input Image:

[image]

Output Image:

[image]

Comment: We can't see either your input or your output image.

Comment: I don't know `processing`, but maybe it is more like Windows and expects carriage returns at the ends of lines rather than the linefeeds you will have got from Python and is therefore not loading the Blue values at the ends of the lines which would make your image yellow... check the first few values in your `pxl` array match the text file you created in Python.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have added them to the post.

Comment: Your output image has an alpha channel, i.e. it is RGBA. Your input image does not. I guess you have to tell `processing` somewhere that the image is just RGB not RGBA, maybe?

Comment: @TimothyBowenc, did you figure out what was the problem? I seem to have the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, my array was ARGB so I was taking the alpha, red and green values. I increased the indexes of the values by 1 and it worked. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Mark Setchell is correct, the blue value was being omitted.
I don't know processing, but maybe it is more like Windows and expects carriage returns at the ends of lines rather than the linefeeds you will have got from Python and is therefore not loading the Blue values at the ends of the lines which would make your image yellow... check the first few values in your pxl array match the text file you created in Python.